# how to set NSPredicate in CoreData fetch

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have an entity with some values in my coreData.
cTitle (string) and price (float)

for example:
cTitle (milk, bread, beer)
price (30, 20, 15);

I need to get values which price is < 20

I'm trying to set predicate

```
NSNumber *pr = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 20.0];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"cPrice > %@)", pr];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

But it crashes with error
 `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "cPrice > %@)"'`

It is single entity, without relationships.

Whats wrong? I can't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `)`  near `%@)"`:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"cPrice < %@", pr];
```